# Blinded manuscripts and arXiv

Tags: publications

Very recently, I have submmited my paper to a journal published by Springer.
As required by the  policy of the journal, the manuscript must not contain the author's name and the corresponding contact information. However, I published the paper to arXiv as a preprint.
My question is What will happen next? My manuscript can be sent to reviewers?
Thank you for your supports.

Comment: The journal should have a policy for precisely this question.

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=arxiv+double-blind ; this has come up quite a few times. My suggestion is "don't worry; if you're thinking about the issue, you're probably already paying more attention than most of the submitters".

Answer (score 2):

Thomas is correct--any journal put out by Springer as well as by university presses will have a specific policy about preprints. Look for the policy on the journal home page or the press's "authors' rights" web page, which often has information for prospective authors (i.e., authors who have submitted a paper for consideration but haven't received a decision). For example, the "Guidelines for Authors' Rights" for the University of Chicago Press's journals division  (https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/cont/jrnl_rights#faq6) states:

"To avoid citation confusion and compromising of peer review, we discourage online posting of pre-prints and working papers. If you choose to submit a pre-publication version of your paper to a non-commercial, discipline-specific pre-print or working paper archive, however, we require that appropriate credit be given to the journal as described above and ask you to remove the working paper from the archive after your article is published or replace it with the published version. Any version of your paper submitted to a pre-print or working paper archive can be made available only under a license that forbids commercial reuse, or you will be required to remit the appropriate fee to make your article available in the journal under a comparable license. If you deposit the published version of your article, it may be made publicly available only after the appropriate embargo period* has been observed. You are responsible for informing the manager of the archive of the embargo period that must be observed.

Please also note the comments elsewhere in these Guidelines regarding prior publication and anonymous peer review and the use of copyrighted material in your article.

*The embargo period is twelve (12) months unless otherwise required by mandate."

So I would advise checking out the specific journal's policy as well as Springer's "authors' rights" pages. Depending on what you find, you may be better off removing your essay from the preprint archive, if that is possible, at least while the essay is under consideration for publication. Good luck!

Comment: "To avoid citation confusion and compromising of peer review, we discourage online posting of pre-prints and working papers." Yeah, sure, that's the reason. To avoid confusion.

Comment: FYI, in the case of arXiv, it is not possible to remove submissions.  There is a "withdraw" option, but this simply marks the paper as "withdrawn"; the public can still download it.